# Mouseover on radio button replacement?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, mouseover, image-replacement

I'm using jQuery to replace my radio buttons on this page - http://www.justdoors.co/product-selection/ and was wondering if it would be possible to add a mouseover effect as well?

I would like for the grey arrows that turn green when selected to change to green on mouseover/hover as the user goes up and down the list.

Comment: You are replacing radio buttons with what?

Comment: @Šime Vidas with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like all your replaced radio buttons have the class "imageCheck" so you could bind the effect on mouseover/mouseout:

```
$('.imageCheck')
    .mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).attr("src", "/changedimage.jpg");
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "/originalimage.jpg");
});
```

Comment: Right... that sort of does what I want it to do but the selected button still stays as green... would like that to grey out while the mouseover is in place on another selection. Would also like the button to change image/colour when the cursor is place on the label for the button

Comment: Also if I select one of the other radio buttons the arrow now doesn't stay 'selected'

Comment: That's just some more JavaScript to add. Set the image of $("#selectedButton") (or whatever you call it) to the grey one when hovering over other images.

Comment: Have uploaded a jsFiddle so you can see what the coding is - http://www.jsfiddle.net/PvS3C/

Answer (score 0):

You could always also use CSS, see an example [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/zTyZh/).